# mysql table status not changed

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am working on one project in which i need to add comet ajax using cakephp and jQuery.

For that i am using [this tutorial](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start).

I have successfully implemented it but now i want to replace text file modification time with mysql table modification time.

I have used `SHOW TABLE STATUS` mysql query and i got mysql table update time but i dont know why somehow table Update_time is not being updated accoringly if i add,modify or delete record.

now please suggest me if i can update that table detail using php code or is there other better way to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: u can find code at the link i provided i just wanted to replace text file implementation with mysql table update time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`SHOW TABLE STATUS` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-table-status.html):

> - `Update_time`
>
>   When the data file was last updated. For some storage engines, this value is `NULL`. For example, `InnoDB` stores multiple tables in its [system tablespace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace) and the data file timestamp does not apply. Even with [file-per-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_file_per_table) mode with each `InnoDB` table in a separate `.ibd` file, [change buffering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_change_buffering) can delay the write to the data file, so the file modification time is different from the time of the last insert, update, or delete. For `MyISAM`, the data file timestamp is used; however, on Windows the timestamp is not updated by updates so the value is inaccurate.

Instead, you can create [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that update a separate table with the current timestamp whenever your table is modified:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log (
  table_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  lastmodified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (table_name)
);

CREATE TRIGGER foo_ins AFTER INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO log (table_name, lastmodified) VALUES ('my_table', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastmodified = NOW();

CREATE TRIGGER foo_ins AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO log (table_name, lastmodified) VALUES ('my_table', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastmodified = NOW();

CREATE TRIGGER foo_ins AFTER DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO log (table_name, lastmodified) VALUES ('my_table', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastmodified = NOW();
```

Comment: @DipeshParmar: No, using a trigger it is possible to track the update time manually.

Comment: Thanx for help i already accepted this answer..Thanx a lot... 100000+ for u.